# My transaction has been pending for over 8h now

Tags: pending-transactions

Wondering if someone could help me, I sent funds using mew and the first fund I sent, maybe I didn't put enough gas, now it's stuck in a limbo with two other payments that I made after first payment.

If you look at etherscan.io, you can see one transaction pending, but if you refresh the page, it will show another transaction pending... Changing the information every 5-10sec... If you look at the etherscan.io page, you will understand what I mean...

etherscan.io/address/0xdd1d9448fa077137488cf909c421a7f394991df9

Are my coins and account lost forever? Can someone help me pls?

Thank you...

Comment: What was the gas you set for your transactions?

Comment: Well It seems the transactions got mined now. I have no clue about the problems.

Answer (score 2):

If a transaction doesn't have enough gas to complete it will not be processed at all and the coins will revert to the original account. The gas paid however will be consumed entirely.

From what I see on etherscan the transactions have only been broadcasted for about 10 minutes. That is a longer time than normal but not anything to raise concern. Worst case the network will eventually drop the transaction if it never gets processed.

Comment: But if you look at the my acct in etherscan.io/address/0xdd1d9448fa077137488cf909c421a7f394991df9 you will see that two transactions retry once every 10min or so... But one transaction  retries to send every 5sec. It's no getting the possibility to run out of gas or anything. The ether isn't even moved from my account... If you open the etherscan.io site and refresh my acct couple of times, while looking at the three transaction times, you will understand what I mean...

Comment: What are you using to send transactions?

Comment: I used my ether wallet...

Comment: Looks like your txs finally got processed.

Answer (score -2):

not sure,

but it looks like the transaction ID #: 0xdd1d9448fa077137488cf909c421a7f394991df9,

the first "d" is lower case whereas the wallet address:
0xDd1d9448Fa077137488cf909C421A7f394991Df9

first "D" is uppercase.

typo!

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ethereum addresses and hashes are not case sensitive, although some wallets may use a checksum. Searching etherscan.io for an address with 'd' vs. 'D' would have no effect.